# Adding a legend to 3D graphics

Tags: graphics3d, legending, labeling

```
In[1]:= Quit

In[2]:= data = 
Import["data.out", "CSV"];
TableForm[%2]
```

The data makes a table like:

Planet 1...Planet 2...Planet 3...Planet 4...etc.

x y z .........x y z .........x y z ........x y z .........

x y z .........x y z .........x y z ........x y z .........

x y z .........x y z .........x y z ........x y z .........

For example here are coordinates of 8 planets going through 6 timesteps from "data.out" which are going to be read:

0,0,0,1.66203e+006,55.6969,2.99196e+006,2.27688e+006,62.4276,1.49598e+006,3.14156e+006,44.024,-4.48794e+006,4.18874e+006,50.3463,0,5.53512e+006,43.7971,0,6.7319e+006,39.7137,0,9.42467e+006,33.5642,0, 0.0579994,0.000421456,0.030788,1.66181e+006,55750.2,2.99156e+006,2.27628e+006,62484.6,1.49559e+006,3.14145e+006,44067.5,-4.48779e+006,4.18844e+006,50395.4,0.0334839,5.53495e+006,43840.4,0.0104742,6.73179e+006,39753.2,0.00452109,9.42461e+006,33597.7,0.00114119, 0.231862,0.00337144,0.123077,1.66115e+006,111430,2.99037e+006,2.27449e+006,124874,1.49441e+006,3.14115e+006,88088.1,-4.48736e+006,4.18753e+006,100733,0.133853,5.53443e+006,87634.3,0.0418678,6.73143e+006,79465.2,0.0180716,9.42443e+006,67161.3,0.00456164, 0.521528,0.0113774,0.276824,1.66005e+006,167080,2.98839e+006,2.2715e+006,187198,1.49244e+006,3.14064e+006,132103,-4.48663e+006,4.18602e+006,151056,0.301062,5.53356e+006,131423,0.0941572,6.73085e+006,119174,0.0406407,9.42413e+006,100724,0.0102588, 0.9269,0.0269648,0.491961,1.65851e+006,222686,2.98562e+006,2.26732e+006,249423,1.4897e+006,3.13993e+006,176110,-4.48562e+006,4.1839e+006,201358,0.535035,5.53235e+006,175203,0.167303,6.73003e+006,158880,0.07221,9.42371e+006,134286,0.0182285, 1.44784,0.0526558,0.768391,1.65653e+006,278233,2.98205e+006,2.26195e+006,311518,1.48617e+006,3.13902e+006,220105,-4.48431e+006,4.18118e+006,251630,0.835664,5.53079e+006,218972,0.261249,6.72897e+006,198579,0.112754,9.42317e+006,167846,0.0284648,

```
In[3]:= Graphics3D[{Point /@ Transpose[Partition[#, 3] & /@ data]}, 
Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Background -> LightBlue, 
ImageSize -> Large]
```

Until here it works perfectly and plots the orbits of the planets (for this example 8 planets, 6 timesteps)

Then I'm trying to make labels for the points like shown below, but it doesn't work.

I want to have one label per planet and not per point, because this program is intendet to plot a lot of points.

Does anyone know how to label these planets? I would be very thankful, if someone could help me!

```
In[4]:= nbody = (Length[Transpose[data]] - 1)/3

Out[4]= 8

In[5]:= PlotLegends -> 
PointLegend[Automatic, 
Table[StringForm["Body ``", n], {n, 1, nbody}]]

Out[6]= PlotLegends -> 
PointLegend[
Automatic, {StringForm["Body ``", 1], StringForm["Body ``", 2], 
StringForm["Body ``", 3], StringForm["Body ``", 4], StringForm[
"Body ``", 5], StringForm["Body ``", 6], StringForm[
"Body ``", 7], StringForm["Body ``", 8]}]
```

Comment: Your sample data, as you describe it, makes no sense. How can planet 1 have `{0,0,0}` as a point on its orbit?

Comment: Thats the sun before the simulation starts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied the sample data you posted and made a CSV file out of it and read into Mathematica like so:

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "data.csv"}];
rawData = First @ Import[path];
data = ArrayReshape[rawData, {6, 8, 3}] // Transpose
```

I don't trust that `data` really represents points along planetary orbits, but it constitutes a data set of 8 lists, each containing 6 triplets, which is good enough for showing how to do the legending.

The major point I want to make is that `PlotLegends` is not an option that can be given to `Graphics3D`. So you must resort to `Legended`, which can add a legend to anything. Like so:

```
Legended[
  Graphics3D[
    {AbsolutePointSize[5], 
     MapThread[{#1, Point[#2]} &, {ColorData[97] /@ Range[8], data}]},
    Axes -> True,
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
    ImageSize -> 400],
  PointLegend[
    ColorData[97] /@ Range[8],
    Row[{"Body ", #}] & /@ Range[8],
    LegendMarkerSize -> 20]]
```

[image: graphics]

Comment: Yes that's perfect, thank you so much!
I just couldn't post more data, but normally there are thousands of more points, so it makes a path, around Body 1 in this case.

Comment: Sorry I checked the supplied data again and it reads in everything in one single row. Actually there should be a new row everytime after it reads 8 times the data, so 8x3 columns and 6 rows in this case.
If it reads in  correctly the following formula:

data = Transpose[Partition[#, 3] & /@ rawdata] 

does the same as:

data = ArrayReshape[rawData, {6, 8, 3}] // Transpose

in your example, just if someone is interested in how it actually works. Now it works great, thank you m_goldberg!

Comment: @UlrichPenitz. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.